# Replace in every nth line starting from a certain line

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I want to replace on every third line starting from second line using sed.

```
Input file
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
.
.
.

Expected output
A1
A2
A3
A4_edit
A5
A6
A7_edit
.
.
.
```

I know there are many solution releted to this is available on stack but for this specific problem, I was unable to find.

My try:

```
sed '1n;s/$/_edit/;n'
```

This only replacing on every second line from the beginning.

Comment: I guess the last `.` in the expected output should actually be `._edit`? Try `sed '4~3 s/$/_edit/' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/vZtO9T).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ seq 10 | sed '1b ; n ; n ; s/$/_edit/'
1
2
3
4_edit
5
6
7_edit
8
9
10_edit
```

This breaks down to a cycle of

- `1b` if this is the first line in the input, start the next cycle, using `sed` default behaviour to print the line and read the next one - which skips the first line in the input
- `n` print the current line and read the next line - which skips the first line in a group of three
- `n` print the current line and read the next line - which skips the second line in a group of three
- `s/$/_edit/` substitute the end of line for `_edit` on the third line of each group of three
- then use the default `sed` behaviour to print, read next line and start the cycle again

If you want to skip more than one line at the start, change `1b` to, say, `1,5b`.

As Wiktor Stribiżew has pointed out in the comments, as an alternative, there is a GNU range extension *`first`*`~`*`step`* which allows us to write

```
sed '4~3s/$/_edit/'
```

which means substitute on every third line starting from line 4.

Comment: @kashiff007 I hope that is enough explanation. I've also included the stepped range syntax suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew in the comments to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are ok with `awk`, try following.

```
awk -v count="-1" '++count==3{$0=$0"_edit";count=0} 1' Input_file
```

Append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

***Explanation:***

```
awk -v count="-1" '     ##Starting awk code here and mentioning variable count whose value is -1 here.
++count==3{             ##Checking condition if increment value of count is equal to 3 then do following.
  $0=$0"_edit"          ##Appending _edit to current line value.
  count=0               ##Making value of count as ZERO now.
}                       ##Closing block of condition ++count==3 here.
1                       ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk`

```
awk 'NR>3&&NR%3==1{$0=$0"_edit"}1' file
A1
A2
A3
A4_edit
A5
A6
A7_edit
A8
A9
A10_edit
A11
A12
A13_edit
```

`NR>3` Test if line is larger then 3
`NR%3==1` and every third line 
`{$0=$0"_edit"}` edit the line
`1` print everything

Answer (score 2):

You can use seds `~` step operator.

```
sed '4~3s|$|_edit|'
```

`~` is a feature of GNU sed, so it will be available in most (all?) distros of Linux. But to use it on macOS (which comes with BSD sed), you would have to install GNU sed to get this feature: `brew install gnu-sed`.

Comment: Perhaps `sed '4~3s/$/_edit/' file` might be a better example bearing in mind the audience that the solution is aimed at, as alternative delimiters for the substitution command (with no benefit) may confuse the beginner.